# Speedometer graphic help w/ jQuery and CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, animation, css, transform

I'm working on a project for shits and giggles to learn CSS3/jQuery animations. I have 10 icons and a speedometer graphic. On the page load the speedometer graphic is rotated to '-60deg' and when the  mousemoves the speedometer graphic moves to a hard coded '-' through '+' angle.

HTML:

```
    <nav class="clearfix" id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="icon first" data-value="1"></a></li>
            <li><a class="icon second" data-value="2"></a></li>
            <li><a class="icon third" data-value="3"></a></li>
            <li><a class="icon forth" data-value="4"></a></li>
            <li><a class="icon fifth" data-value="5"></a></li>
            <li><a class="icon sixth" data-value="6"></a></li>
            <li><a class="icon seventh" data-value="7"></a></li>
            <li><a class="icon eight" data-value="8"></a></li>
            <li><a class="icon nine" data-value="9"></a></li>
            <li><a class="icon ten" data-value="10"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<div id="footer-container">
    <div id="speedometer"></div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".icon").hover(function()
    {
        var ICON_NAME = $(this).attr("data-value");
        switch(ICON_NAME)
        {
            case '1':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({roate: '-60deg'});
                break;
            case '2':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: '-60deg'});
                break;
            case '3':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: '-40deg'});
                break;              
            case '4':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: '-30deg'});
                break;              
            case '5':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: '-20deg'});
                break;              
            case '6':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: '0deg'});
                break;      
            case '7':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: '30deg'});
                break;
            case '8':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: '40deg'});
                break;
            case '9':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: '50deg'});
                break;                                                                  
            case '10':
                $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: '60deg'});
                break;
        }
    });
})();
```

So that's all cool - but I have two problems: 1.) It doesn't seem to detect the first icon (only 2 through 10) and 2.) once I move the mouse over an icon for the first time after page load, it bounces to the '0deg' position and then to the current position. How can I fix these two problems? The jumping to 0deg before animating to this current position is my biggest question.

** NOTE **
The speedometer's initial position is set to '-60deg' via CSS3 transforms.

LINK TO LIVE EXAMPLE:
[Speedometer Example](http://skullbox.fatcow.com/tests/speedometer/)

Comment: positions `1` and `2` seem to both be set at `-60deg` And you have a typo on the first case, rotate is spelled wrong.

Comment: Due to the nature of this question, it may help to also post relevant CSS.

Comment: Hi, I've provided a link to my code. It seems to be working okay now, but I think it can be improved. [Speedometer Example](http://skullbox.fatcow.com/tests/speedometer/)

Answer (score 1):

Nice work!  You can make simple interactions like this much cleaner by just filling out the `data` attributes.

```
<nav class="clearfix" id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="icon first" data-value="-60deg"></a></li>
        <li><a class="icon second" data-value="-40deg"></a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>

<script>
$(function(){
  $(".icon").hover(function(){
    var degs = $(this).attr("data-value");
    $("#speedometer").stop(true, true).animate({rotate: degs});
  });
});
</script>
```